# POJO with @Column annotaion giving 400 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am having a DTO where there are columns annotated like this

```
@Column(name="created_by")
private String createdBy;
```

When I am passing this DTO to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/smap", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ServiceResponse  smap(@RequestBody  DTO dto)
```

It is giving 400 error.

If I remove @Column then it is working fine.

How can I pass the DTO with @column to spring

Comment: What does the JSON you are POSTing to the method look like?

Comment: {
 "createdBy":"1", 
 "createdDate":12-12-2016, 
 "customerId":1,  
 "updatedBy":"1", 
 "updatedDate":,
 "volume":1,
 "weight":1
}

Comment: Is it Column from javax.persistence? It's probably not an error on the request itself but when trying to persist data

Comment: yes. it is Column from javax.persistence. It is not going inside controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Pretty silly actually. CreatedDate time format is giving the problem. Thanks for your help.